# remove a line that contains a specific character

Tags: java

I have a text file structured like this, this is just a sample:

```
# Timestamp, X, Y, MAC Address of AP, RSS
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:85:a4:01 -77
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:85:a4:02 -77
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:a2 -72
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:04:c2 -69
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:04:d1 -86
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:04:d2 -87
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:85:a4:12 -96
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:03:f1 -65
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:03:f2 -67
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:03:e2 -61
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:84:92:12 -95
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:85:a4:00 -77
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:04:d0 -87
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:87:03:f0 -70
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b1 -90
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b2 -92
1395422922871 6.241992473602295 0.9473437666893005 00:1a:1e:8e:e9:b0 -91
```

I would like to write a Java program that searches for the following characters: 00:1a:1e:85:a4:00 and 00:1a:1e:87:04:d0 and removes the lines that containes those characters.

I have the following program:

```
public class extract {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String lineToRemove = "00:1a:1e:87:04:d0";
    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
        String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
        if(trimmedLine.equals(lineToRemove)) continue;
        writer.write(currentLine);
    }

    writer.close();
    boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }

}
```

but it can only remove the characters that matches the entire line and the output file is contained in just one line, do you have any recommendations on what do I have to modify to obtain the desired output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I think it should look like. I may have the formatting wrong on the try () bit, but see if this compiles.

Java 1.6:

```
public class Extract {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        final File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
        final File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

            final String lineToRemove1 = "00:1a:1e:87:04:d0";
            final String lineToRemove2 = "00:1a:1e:85:a4:00";
            String currentLine;

            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                final String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if (!currentLine.contains(lineToRemove1) 
                        && !currentLine.contains(lineToRemove2)) {
                    writer.write(currentLine);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) { 
                reader.close();
            }
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java 1.7+ :

```
public class Extract {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

        final File inputFile = new File("myFile.txt");
        final File tempFile = new File("myTempFile.txt");

        try(
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
            final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));
        ) {

            final String lineToRemove1 = "00:1a:1e:87:04:d0";
            final String lineToRemove2 = "00:1a:1e:85:a4:00";
            String currentLine;

            while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // trim newline when comparing with lineToRemove
                final String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                if (!currentLine.contains(lineToRemove1) 
                        && !currentLine.contains(lineToRemove2)) {
                    writer.write(currentLine);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) { 
                reader.close();
            }
            if (writer != null) {
                writer.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also sounds like user3349667 should write a line break each time so that the resulting file isn't all on one line:
    writer.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));

Comment: thank you but I would also like to remove 2 or more lines at the same time. any recommendations for that requirement?

Comment: Good deal. I like writer.newLine().

Comment: @user3349667 I don't know what that means. Your while statement is looking at each line one at a time. You either put the line in the new file or not.

Comment: Sorry, what I wanted to say is that I would like to search for 2 characters at the same time, if any of those 2 is found remove a line.

Comment: Better yet use a *try-with-resources* on the reader and writer.

Comment: @user3349667 you can use 
`if (!trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove1)&&
 !trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove2)) { writer.write(currentLine);
writer.newLine();}`

Comment: the statement if !(trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) should be written as if (!trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) right?

Comment: @skiwi ++ I'm not allowed to use Java 7 yet, so I forget about the sugar.

Comment: @user3349667 that was typo .however I made that edit. should be reflected soon

Comment: guys so how does the final code should look like? I'm having a hard time inserting the "try,finally" blocks

Comment: I have the following errors "Extract must be defined on its own file", "Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7", "reader/writer cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Hey Eric, if I want to include the string 00:1a:1e:87:04:d0 and the string 00:1a:1e:85:a4:00 is it possible in the same variable?

Comment: @user3349667 No. If you have multiple values, you could have some collection, like Set<String>, and iterate through that. With only two, I think it's much more clear to make them explicit.